# How do you do server side rendering with eureka and springMVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am trying to create a set of springMVC microservices with server side rendering using JSPs. My springMVC apps are having controllers that returns model objects to JSP's that does the view.

My JSP's are in "META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp/" folder. When I run the Springboot application it works without any issue and my model gets displayed properly in the browser.

However when I use eureka with zuul to do service registry and go through a common app service, I am getting the following error

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are  seeing this as a fallback.
Wed Aug 24 23:30:25 IST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
GENERAL
```

And in the console it states

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:158) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:133) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:79) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.5.RELEASE]
at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:120) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
```

Any idea why I am getting this. I think this is due to the way that I might be having the JSP's (view) rendered.

Comment: You haven't provided much context. Can you include details on the forwarding rules you have set in Zuul? Maybe a `DEBUG` level logging on the Zuul server to determine what it is trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the quick response. I found this to be a an issue with my understanding of zuul routes. Once I corrected the routes everything worked properly through eureka.